# AJAX Requests when User is logged out

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am making **many** AJAX requests in my ASP.net application, but now, when the user is logged out, the login form just shows up wherever I am using the response text.

How can I handle this problem? I cannot re-concept all the responses so that if the user is logged out, I get a certain response, because they are *too many*.

Is there a way I can handle this for all responses? All responses are handled by Generic Halndlers .ashx in a certain folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can acheive this across the site using a comman function to verify the session.This can be acheived using 2 step process

STEP1:

In ajax complete function call validateSession in which you will redirect to login page based on session/login page content.

```
complete: function(XHR, status){   //handle session out
            validateSession(XHR.responseText);
        },
```

STEP2:

now handle the session and redirect by checking some text placed in login page.In my example i placed :SESSION EXPIRED: string in login page

```
   function validateSession(strAjaxOutput, strStatus, objXhr)
    {
    if(("undefined" != typeof strStatus) && ("undefined" != typeof objXhr))
    {
    strAjaxOutput = objXhr.responseText;
    }
    var reg = /:SESSION EXPIRED:/;
    if(reg.test(strAjaxOutput))
    {
    window.location = "http://www.myloginpage.com"; //redirect to login page
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I really like the idea behind your solution. I'm giving it a try.

Comment: WC.This is how i am following on mysite and it is a working solution :)